# Grant Permission to CREATE tables - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the SQL command for giving a user permissions to create (and delete) tables?  I am looking for something similar to this:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT ON Customers TO Joe
```

I have spent some time Googling for the answer.

Comment: you Googled and no answers for such simple question?

Comment: What exactly you googled? I get lots of [results](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=zEM0U7mEN4PY8gefuYHgBA&gws_rd=cr#q=grant+permission+to+create+table+in+sql+server)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When I googled, I got right to [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx). It looks like you want:

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE
```

As in:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO MelanieK;
GO
```

Answer (score 26):

**Two Options**

1. `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO Joe AS dbo`
2. Add the user to the fixed database role: `db_ddladmin`

Comment: Using db_ddladmin is way too much for what the OP asked here and it is really bad idea to give a user "extra" permission if you do not have to. You should give the minimum permission as must.

Comment: @RonenAriely Agreed but can you say what permission to add that can be added with the UI.  I am looking for the permission I can using the UI.