# I am getting error in grant command in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am getting the error in assign rights to a user using `grant` in SQL Server 2012.

SQL:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, VIEW DEFINITION 
ON test TO [logintest]
```

Error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object 'test', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: go through this it may help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692024/grant-permission-to-create-tables-sql-server

Comment: The Query and Error message does not seems to match

Comment: Either **test** doesn't exists in the db/schema you are connected to. Or your user doesnt have access to give grant

Answer (score 2):

If the "test" table or database object is not in the "dbo" schema, you should explicitly set the schema name in the GRANT command as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, VIEW DEFINITION 
ON Sales.Orders TO [logintest]
```

On this case the Orders table is in the Sales schema

[image]

Or as the error message indicates, you may not have the required permissions to give permissions to an other user

Answer (score 1):

hi please see grant syntax

```
  Grant privilageName on objectName  To{userName/Public/roleName} [with Grant opion]
```

example

```
grant select on tbl_login to user24
```