# Fix "All permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility"

Tags: sql-server, sql-grant

I am trying to run SQL Server query using this code below, each time query is executed I get the error.

> The ALL permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility. It DOES NOT imply ALL permissions defined on the entity.

```
use eNtsaMemberRegistrationDB
go
grant all on TestUser to Users;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "ALL" would imply granting the user all of the following permissions:

```
 - BACKUP DATABASE
 - BACKUP LOG
 - CREATE DATABASE
 - CREATE DEFAULT
 - CREATE FUNCTION
 - CREATE PROCEDURE
 - CREATE RULE
 - CREATE TABLE
 - CREATE VIEW
```

I would recommend identifying each permission the user requires and adding them individually to avoid including anything that you might not be aware/certain of and jeopardizing the security of your database.

Comment: The reason why i am granting permission to the table, i had experience databasesql client exception for user being failed to login. Here is my code for my 

namespace eNtsaPortalWebsiteProject
{
    public class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterAuth()
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyString", "Users", "UserName", "FullName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
    }
}

Comment: If the application that is executing the SQL command is connecting to the database as the TestUser user, then you should just require CREATE TABLE permission for that user role.

Comment: Hi @Oren, i think i can follow, any example perhaps i might use to execute?

Comment: Hi all i m trying this sql command and still not getting anywhere. use[master]
go
create login[DOMAIN\Users] FROM Windows WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
go
use[eNtsaMemberRegistrationDB]
go
create user[DOMAIN\Users] for Login[DOMAIN\Users]
go
use[eNtsaMemberRegistrationDB]
go
alter role[db_datareader] ADD MEMBER[DOMAIN\Users]

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22692127/4002791
Hope that helps.